# Is there any way to replace values in HTML tags by a variable and ask values to construct the html?

Tags: javascript, html

1) Let's say, my email template looks like this: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_cafe

I am looking for a solution that allows me to declare variables like this in the HTML code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2F7R2ICIWLW

In this example, you can see, I have mentioned the hyperlink source as  variables.:

```
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-row w3-padding w3-black">
    <div class="w3-col s3">
      <a href="@home" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s3">
      <a href="@about" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s3">
      <a href="@menu" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black">MENU</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s3">
      <a href="@where" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black">WHERE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

similar for the text as well:

`<p>@myrow1text</p>`

How can I create a solution in JavaScript that asks me the values of ALL variables defined on the HTML code in separate textboxes then when I enter all the values, and click on SUBMIT button, it gives me the complete HTML with replaced values so I can copy the HTML code and use it anywhere?

Comment: you will have to create and render the template. check this http://jtemplates.tpython.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `interpolate` method can help you

```js
(() => {
  const interpolate = (str, ...tokenCollection) => 
    tokenCollection && tokenCollection[0] instanceof Object
      ? tokenCollection
        .map( token => str
                .replace(/{?[a-z_0-9]+}/gi, key =>
                  token[key.replace(/[{}]/g, "")] || key ) )
      : str;
  const html = document.querySelector("#example").innerHTML;
  const createReplacement = ([home, about, menu, where]) => 
    ({home, about, menu, where});
  const replacements1 = createReplacement(["/home", "/about", "/menu", "/where"]);
  const replacements2 = createReplacement(["/home2", "/about2", "/menu2", "/where2"]);
  document.querySelector("#result").textContent = 
     interpolate(html, replacements1, replacements2).join("\n");
})()
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>

<template id="example">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="{home}">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="{about}">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="{menu}">MENU</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="{where}">WHERE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a code, but couldn't finish it. Maybe you, or someone else could fix the last issue))

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/17vtmoq4/)

```
<textarea id="ENTER">Here your HTML with multiple (same) variables @BUBU</textarea>

<button id="create">Create</button>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<div id="content">Appending created textareas here</div>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('create').addEventListener('click',function(){
  let E = document.getElementById('ENTER');
  let N = E.value.match(/@BUBU/g).length; //getting the number of your variables

  for(let i = 0; i < N; i++){//creating N textareas with class="moo"
    let Z = document.createElement('textarea');
    Z.className = "moo";
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(Z);
  }  
});

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function(){
  let M = document.getElementsByClassName("moo");//getting created textareas
  let E = document.getElementById('ENTER');
  let x;
  for(let i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
    //here it must replace each @BUBU with entered value of area, but it doesn't
    x = E.value.replace(/@BUBU/ig,M[i].value);
  }    
  document.getElementById('result').value = x;   
});
```

Comment: This is great - what exactly is the issue? I did one test and it looks like last value is being assigned to all  tags.